# Extract coefficient numeric for r plot legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to get the legend in a simple R plot to report the coefficient (i.e. slope) without manually extracting the value. Does anybody know how to code the legend so that it displays the value rather than the command? Thanks

```
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- sample(rnorm(100), 100, replace = TRUE)
plot(x, y)
mod <- lm(y ~x)
abline(lm(y~x))
legend("topleft", "Slope = coef(mod)[2]", col = "black", pch = 15, cex = .8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
paste0("Slope = ", coef(mod)[2])
```